# Problems with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I cant transfer any of the relatet posts to my simple problem.
In order to get into GridBagLayout i wrote a simple example:

```
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   JPanel main =new JPanel(); 
   frame.setContentPane(main);
   GridBagLayout gbl=new GridBagLayout();
   GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
   main.setLayout(gbl);
   JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
   JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");

   gbc.gridx=0;
   gbc.gridy=0;
   gbc.gridheight=1;
   gbc.gridwidth=1;
   gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
   gbl.setConstraints(btn1, gbc);
   gbc.gridx=0;
   gbc.gridy=1;
   gbl.setConstraints(btn2, gbc);

   frame.setSize(new Dimension(200,100));

  main.add(btn1);
   main.add(btn2);
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

Here i have the Problem that neither .fill nor any other parameter of GBConstrains sems to work. I ever get the two buttons in the middle of the window.

thx in advance

Comment: 1) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration of your `GridBagConstraint` are incorrect:

- `fill` can only take: `NONE`, `VERTICAL`, `HORIZONTAL` or `BOTH`.
- `anchor` can use relative location within a "cell"
- `fill` and `anchor` almost always require to use `weightx/weighty`
- Try to avoid using `gridx` and `gridy` because they get hard to maintain. Instead use their default value (`RELATIVE`) and you can change the value of `gridwidth`/`gridheight` to set it to `1` (or more if needed) and `REMAINDER` to make the layout wrap to next line/column (components are then positionned in the order they were added to the container.

Here is a working code of yours (although I am not sure of the exact layout you were targetting):

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGBL {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        JPanel main = new JPanel(gbl);
        frame.setContentPane(main);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        main.setLayout(gbl);
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");

        gbl.setConstraints(btn1, gbc);
        gbl.setConstraints(btn2, gbc);

        main.add(btn1);
        main.add(btn2);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestGBL().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I made a sample application that demonstrates how to use GridBadLayout that is reusing the constraints:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;



    public class Test1 {

        private JFrame frame;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Test1 window = new Test1();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Create the application.
         */
        public Test1() {
            initialize();
        }

        /**
         * Initialize the contents of the frame.
         */
        private void initialize() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
            gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0};
            gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
            gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

            JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test1");
            GridBagConstraints gbc_btnTest = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_btnTest.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gbc_btnTest.gridx = 0;
            gbc_btnTest.gridy = 0;
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnTest, gbc_btnTest);

            JButton btnTest_1 = new JButton("Test2");
            gbc_btnTest.gridx = 1;
            gbc_btnTest.gridy = 0;
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnTest_1, gbc_btnTest);
        }

    }
```

Comment: There is no need to have separate GridBagConstraints. You still have to set the contraints properly, whether you use one or multiple contraints.

Comment: I was under the impression that reusing the GridBagConstraint would result in both buttons have the same values for gridx and gridy. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: @noamik Just to clarify, no. There is no "need" to create new instances of GBC but in some cases it is more cautious.

Comment: I just tested it and you are right. I couldn't edit the comment above anymore though, so I just provided a new simplified example in my initial answer ...

Comment: Okay Thank you. Then i just found out, that i cant overwrite used grids.. so i forget GridBagLayout xD .. Any other idea, how i can achiev a resizing of one Component by just invisible another Component in the frame.? i mean sth like                      [[Panel1]  [Panel2]]<-->[[panel2]] ?

Comment: If you invisible one panel and redraw the entire frame, the other one should expand ...

Comment: You might want to dig through those introductions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/

Comment: Once you got the idea, you should start with selecting the proper layout manager for your task: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#choosing
And make sure to look into the properties columnWeights and rowWeights for GridBagLayout and similar ones for other LayoutManagers ...